# De-Serializing generic sublass with object backing field

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization, subclassing

Not sure how to title this question correctly but here is the problem.

```
public sealed class ObjectPropertySubclassTest
{
    private sealed class CleverBaseClassConverter : JsonConverter<BaseClass>
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, BaseClass value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override BaseClass ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, BaseClass existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            if (token["Components"] is JArray)
            {
                var collection=new CollectionClass();
                serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), collection);
                return collection;
            }
            else
            {
                if (token["Value"] is JArray)
                {
                    var obj = new SubClass<IEnumerable<BaseClass>>();
                    serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), obj);
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    var obj = new SubClass<object>();
                    serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), obj);
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CleverBaseClassConverter))]
    private abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    private class SubClass<T>: BaseClass
    {
        public new T Value
        {
            get => (T) base.Value;
            set => base.Value = value;
        }
    }

    private sealed class CollectionClass : SubClass<IEnumerable<BaseClass>>
    {
        public IEnumerable<BaseClass> Components { get=>Value; set=>Value=value; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeValue() => false;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var item=new CollectionClass
        {
            Components=new BaseClass[] {new SubClass<string>{Value="hi"},new SubClass<int>{Value=5},   }
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        var copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionClass>(json);

        //why does copy.components have 4 items (2 doubling up)?
        //why does copy.value have 4 items (2 doubling up) as well?
    }
}
```

Serializaiton works as expected but when i deserialize json into a collection class, it ends up with 4 items instead of 2 (in components). Am i doing something fundamentally wrong here with deserialization?
Also why does it still serialize "Value" for collection class

JSON: (I have json converter to deserialize correct subclass)

```
{"Components":[{"Value":"hi"},{"Value":5}],"Value":[{"Value":"hi"},{"Value":5}]}
```

Comment: When you change **TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All** it will be **2**, right?

Comment: Yes but why? and i want to eventually use custom json converters to handle subclass deserialization

Comment: Use TypeNameHandling.Auto instead of TypeNameHandling.Object

Comment: i used type handling in this example to simplify the question but i want to actually use json converter to decide what subclass is initialised

Comment: i have updated my question with json converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work and why was it duplicating items

```
private class SubClass<T>: BaseClass
{
    public new T Value
    {
        get => (T) base.Value;
        set => base.Value = value;
    }

    //Added this here in the generic subclass
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeValue() => true;
}
```

Then in the collection subsclass

```
private sealed class CollectionClass : SubClass<IEnumerable<BaseClass>>
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseClass> Components { get=>Value; set=>Value=value; }

    //this prevents value to be serialized for this type of class
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue() => false;
}
```

**Finally Why it was duplicating it?**
Because value was serialized and it was aggregating "components" after deserializing value part, after deserializing value it would deserialize coponents which took already deserialized list of values as base and added components to that collection. so stopping value from serializing in case of collection class it would not have underlying json for "values" and hence would not duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TypeNameHandling.Auto
```

instead of

```
TypeNameHandling.Object
```